# How to run vbs file and pass argument/parameter to bat file?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, parameters

This VBS will help me to hide the CMD prompt when calling a batch file. Both files are in the same location.

Here is my VBS code:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "b.bat" & Wscript.Arguments.Item(0),0, False
```

Here is the batch file code:

```
if [%1]==[] GOTO :EXIT
Echo abc > %1
:EXIT
```

and I start my command prompt like this:

```
c:...\Desktop>a.vbs "a.txt"
```

The error I get says this:

```
Error: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The batch file will create an empty `txt` file whose name is specified as a parameter.

Appreciate you help. Thanks.

Comment: can you share more code?

Comment: I added more code. Thanks for helping and reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with spaces in your command. This:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "b.bat" & Wscript.Arguments.Item(0),0, False
```

Should be:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "b.bat " & Wscript.Arguments.Item(0),0, False
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. Appreciate your help :D